# How to change style of an element in React without using querySelector?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to the React. Here, I'm trying to override the CSS of a class based on a condition

```
let customizeColumn = document.querySelector(".main-table-body");
!expandFilter ? customizeColumn.setAttribute("style", `height:calc(100vh - 345px)`) : customizeColumn.setAttribute("style", `height:calc(100vh - 302px)`);
```

Here, I am managing the state of this variable and I am calling toggleFilter on the button click

```
const [expandFilter, toggleFilter] = useState(false);
```

But I don't want to use `document.querySelector(".main-table-body")` to fetch the class, Is there any other way of doing this. I am using `Material-UI` too. If that helps

Answer (score 0):

In the render of the `main-table-body`, check the state to determine what CSS property it should have, eg:

```
return (
  <table 
    class="main-table-body"
    style={{ height: `calc(100vh - ${expandFilter ? 302 : 345}px)` }}
  >
    // table contents
  </table>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply style using style attribute.

In the render method do like this

```
const pixelsToReduce= expandFilter ? 302 : 345
const height=`calc(100vh - pixelsToReduce)`
return (
  <table
     class="main-table-body"
     style={{height:height}}
  >
  </table>
)
```